# Rational result, how? $\int_{1}^{2}{\mathrm dx\over e^x\ln(x+1)}={27\over 100}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, rational-numbers

$$\int_{1}^{2}{\mathrm dx\over e^x\ln(x+1)}={27\over 100}$$

Can this be possible? The result of rational, it is not supposed to be.

$e^x=1+x+{x^2\over 2!}+{x^3\over 3!}+\cdots$

Comment: Why shouldn't that be rational? Can you show us the calculations you used to get that, then we can maybe point out a flaw, and tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: because most of these integral mostly give irrational constant

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integration&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22Integral%22,+%22integrand%22%7D+-%3E%22exp(-x)%2Flog(x%2B1)%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22Integral%22,+%22variable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22Integral%22,+%22rangestart%22%7D+-%3E%221%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22Integral%22,+%22rangeend%22%7D+-%3E%222%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,+%22integration%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D) says that it is $0.26999879...$

Comment: As you say "most" and "mostly", sometimes coincidences happen. While the integral is not $27/100$ (now we have two different people saying so) nobody seem to have ruled out that it could be rational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prove that it is $\frac{27}{100}$ because it isn't. It's about $0.2699988\ldots$

Comment: interesting @Jose it is almost an integer. Freak of nature right? Or it has a closed form?

Comment: By numeric approximation? Then it could still be rational.

Comment: @black I doubt it has a closed form.

Comment: An integer? And there are rational numbers whose decimal expension starts like that.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, by numeric approximation. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, yes it a rational value @Henrik

Comment: $\exp(-\tfrac{16}7\exp(-2)-1)$ is pretty close.

Comment: impressive @g.kov how did you get it so close?

Comment: @black: [ries](https://mrob.com/pub/ries/index.html) -s -Ox -l4 0.269998792686495290